# Prevent overlapping docked elements

Tags: .net, visual-studio, overlap, designer

Having a element docked in "fill" mode, another one on "right":

Expected:

```
_________________________
|             ||    2    |
|      1      ||_________|
|             |
|_____________|
```

Got

```
_________________________
|              |    2    |
|          1   |_________|
|                        |
|________________________|
```

It depends on the order by which you put the elements in the designer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the offending group box (block 1 in the example) then click the "Bring to Front" button in the context menu.

[Source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?490344-RESOLVED-How-can-I-prevent-Dock-quot-fill-quot-from-overlapping-other-objects)